# How customize values on products filter bar wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, custom-fields

I need to modify the value and name of the products filter in a Wordpress template that I've purchased.
The template is [Automotive - Templatic](http://templatic.com/cms-themes/automotive-responsive-vehicle-directory). I need to change values and name of filter products filter. I'm trying to change this PHP code:

```
        <form id="search_car" name="search_car" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>" method="get">
            <input type="hidden" name="search" id="search" value="vehicle" />               
                <div class="selectbox select1">
                    <input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php _e('Model , Name etc...',T_DOMAIN); ?>">
                </div>
                <span class="shape2"><?php _e('OR',T_DOMAIN); ?></span>             
            <?php if($post_category): ?>
                <div class="selectbox select2">
                    <select class="select" title="<?php _e("All Makes",T_DOMAIN); ?>" name="makes" id="makes">
                        <option value=""><?php _e("All Makes",T_DOMAIN); ?></option>
                        <?php
                         $args = array( 'taxonomy' => 'vcategory' );
                         $terms = get_terms( 'vcategory',$args);
                         foreach ( $terms as $term ):
                         ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $term->term_id; ?>" <?php if($_REQUEST['makes'] == $term->term_id){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>><?php echo esc_attr( $term->name ); ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?> 
                    </select>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($model_status): ?>
                <div class="selectbox select2">
                    <select class="select" title="<?php _e('All Models',T_DOMAIN); ?>" name="status" id="model_status">
                       <option value=""><?php _e('All Models',T_DOMAIN); ?></option>
                       <?php 
                            $explode = explode(",",$option);
                            foreach($explode as $_explode):
                       ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $_explode; ?>" <?php if($_REQUEST['status'] == $_explode){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>><?php echo sprintf(__('%s',T_DOMAIN),$_explode); ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php if($fuel): ?>
                <div class="selectbox select2">
                    <select class="select" title="<?php _e('All Type',T_DOMAIN); ?>" name="fuel" id="fuel">
                        <option value=""><?php _e('All Type',T_DOMAIN); ?></option>
                        <?php
                            $fuel_exp = explode(",",$fuel_option);
                            foreach($fuel_exp as $_fuel_option): 
                        ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $_fuel_option; ?>" <?php if($_REQUEST['fuel'] == $_fuel_option){ ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>><?php echo sprintf(__('%s',T_DOMAIN),$_fuel_option); ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

I have to create 3 dropdown fields and 1 text area field. Can you help me? 
Thanks in advance...